# Написать метод/функцию, который на вход принимает массив городов, выводит их через запятую, в конце ставит точку

Tags: javascript

Написать метод/функцию, который на вход принимает массив городов, выводит их через запятую, в конце ставит точку.
Пример:
«Севастополь, Москва, Ростов.»

Comment: День добрый. С чем именно у вас возникли трудности?

Comment: С тем, что я начал изучать javascript и мне необходимо получить ответ, чтобы понять, как это работает. Спасибо.

Comment: Может тогда стоит начать с основ, а не просить готовое решение?

Comment: Так я и начал, только вот всё равно трудности возникают. Поверьте, сюда я пришёл уже в последнюю очередь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function CherezZapjatuju(arr) {
  return arr.join(",") + ".";
}
console.log(CherezZapjatuju(["Севастополь", "Москва", "Ростов", "Chicago"]));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Александр На здоровье. Успехов! "Галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: Готово! Спасибо ещё раз!

Comment: А есть смысл использовать двойные кавычки?

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько Мне больше нравятся двойные, хотя одинарные лучше в смысле экономии чернил.